# Ссылка на главную страницу на Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Роут стоит такой:

`Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome');});`

Но если прописать в ссылке `<a href="/">`, то открывается директория с папками. Как прописать ссылке, чтобы перейти на главную?

Comment: пишите не прямые ссылки, а используйте именованеые роуты и функцию route();

Answer (score 1):

Директория соответствует корню? Если видны файлы index.php, .htaccess и т.п., то нужно настроить Apache.

Например,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName yoursite.laravel
        ServerAlias www.yoursite.laravel
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/yoursite.laravel/htdocs/
        RewriteEngine on
        **DirectoryIndex index.php**
        <Directory /var/www/html/yoursite.laravel/htdocs/>
                Options FollowSymlinks
               AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Иначе не будет обрабатывать файл index.php.

Comment: Вариант с  настройками  конфигураций  htaccess, а тем более с apache. не рассматриваю, всё должно быть предусмотрено в самом фреймворке, а если не предусмотрено, то зачем он тогда нужен.

Comment: @SebastianMelmot если при проектировке веб-приложения Вы не рассматриваете конфигурацию сервера под приложение, то не стоит этим заниматься вовсе.

Comment: Сконфигурировать то сервер я смогу, не проблема, но только если пишу на чистом коде, а при использовании фрейморков хотелось бы чтобы это оставалось под капотом, в этом же их принцип и основная философия

Comment: Под капотом у вас остается большая часть функций реализующих маршруты, защиту данных, подключение к БД и работу с БД, вспомогательные функции, генерирование страниц и т.д. При написании чистого кода (смотря что вы считаете чистым), вы увеличиваете себе объем работы и если это большое приложение, то в конечном итоге вы создадите велосипед, но чисто под себя.
Использование инструментов в связке (php + mysql + apache) это норма для веба. 
Даже в инструкции Laravel предполагается настройка Apache или Nginx https://laravel.com/docs/5.7

Comment: Вы можете использовать встроенный веб-сервер в php (http://php.net/manual/ru/features.commandline.webserver.php):
php -S localhost:8000 (из каталога с файлом index.php) или php artisan serve из папки приложения (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/installation)

Answer (score 1):

Все дело в настройках сервера. Увидев Ваш комментарий под одним из ответов, хочу сказать, что настройку сервера Вы будете делать всегда и везде, если хотите реализовать единую точку входа.

Точка входа в приложениях Laravel лежит в папке public, где также лежат статические файлы. К примеру, на том же ubuntu, путь к папке будет таким: `/var/www/html/laravel.app/public/`

Вам следует настроить Ваш сервер под использование фреймворка. Например, вот настройки для apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com

ServerAdmin admin@example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public

<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сначала даем имя роуту

`Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome');})->name('index');`

Далее выводим его в представлении

`<a href="{{ route('index') }}">index</a>`

Comment: Тут дело не в именовании роута, а в настройках apache/nginx

Comment: @Alexxosipov да я уже понял, тут можно просто реорганизовать структуру фреймворка и вынести index.php из public на уровень выше. Я уже не стал этого советовать

Comment: Очень плохая практика, поскольку в public/, кроме точки входа, лежит статика. Правильно, что не стали этого советовать :)

Comment: И в чем проблема? Фреймворк это всего лишь набор библиотек, с настраиваемыми параметрами. Необязательно придерживаться его структуры аликейшена

Comment: Как минимум, в нарушении концепции. Не вижу ни единой причины так делать. В любом случае, для отдачи статики необходимо переадресовывать запросы на /public.

Comment: Вы программист и сами принимаете решение, какими средствами и как задача должна быть решена. Вы пишите на языке, а не на фреймворке, следовательно о какой концепции фреймворка может идти речь(я о архитектуре аликейшена)? Возьмем, к примеру, сервис Яндекс.Еда на Симфони. Вы думаете что их апликейшн построен на примере от Симфони?